# PHPMailer - Various Problems

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

So I've made an app that is supposed to send email when the user performs actions.
On my local server (wamp). Sending these emails was not an issue.

I purchased a shared linux hosting (indian server) form bigrock.

Initially I tested the mailing function on my hosting itself.
i.e. the to and from email id's were both xyz@mydomain.com.
This worked without any issues.

But then I tried with other mail services. And I either get the error "Could not Authenticate" (On gmail, I have less secured apps turned on).

On yahoo and my company email I'm getting "SMTP->Connect() Error".

I tried disabling $email->IsSMTP(); 
This would work if sending to xyz@mydomain.com
But gives error if sending to any other domain. ERROR :Could not instantiate mail function.

I've been pulling my hair out trying to sort this error. I've already read hundreds of Q/A here and github.

Below is my Code

```
function my_SendEmail($quote,$message,$params,$details)
{
    $return=array(0,"Email Sent");
    // Connection Settings
    $settings=$params;
    //print_r($settings);
    $from=$details->from;
    $mailer=$details->mailer;
    $subject=$details->subject;

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                                // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                    // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->IsSMTP();                                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = gethostbyname($settings->host);           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = $settings->login;                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = $settings->password;                  // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = $settings->security;                // Enable TSL encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = $settings->port;                          // TCP port to connect to
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array( 'ssl' => array(
                                                    'verify_peer' => false,
                                                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                                                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                                                  )
                                  );
        //From
        $mail->setFrom($from, $mailer);

        //Recipients
        $mail->addAddress($details->to,$details->recipientName);     // Add a recipient           // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo($from, $mailer);
        foreach($quote->cc as $cc)
        {
            $mail->addCC($cc);
        }
        //Attachments
        foreach($quote->attachments as $file)
        {
            $mail->addAttachment($file);    // Add attachments  // Optional name
        }
        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $message;
        $mail->AltBody = 'Non-HTML Mail Clients Not Supported, Please View This email in a browser or get a HTML friendly Email Client.';
        $mail->send();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $return=array(1,'Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Error When SMPT is enabled.

```
2019-02-18 08:37:57 Connection: opening to ssl://103.20.215.161:465, timeout=300, options=array (  &#039;ssl&#039; =&gt;   array (    &#039;verify_peer&#039; =&gt; false,    &#039;verify_peer_name&#039; =&gt; false,    &#039;allow_self_signed&#039; =&gt; true,  ),)<br>
2019-02-18 08:39:00 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://103.20.215.161:465 (Connection timed out) [/home/justq3zt/public_html/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php line 325]<br>
2019-02-18 08:39:00 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)<br>
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting<br>
[1,"Error: SMTP connect() failed. https:\/\/github.com\/PHPMailer\/PHPMailer\/wiki\/Troubleshooting"]
```

I've checked all the parameters supplied and they are the correct ones.

I need help. This is the last thing stopping me from delivering this project. And sending mails is the primary function of this app.

PS : I checked the php extensions on bigrock. There's no option of openssl there. Could that be a problem? 
Update : Checked this using

```
<?php echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."\n"; ?>
```

It says "SSL Loaded"..So i guess the extension is loaded.

Comment: In many cases this problem occurs to me due to varying SMTP ports.
Sometimes I use `465` in dev and have to use `587` or even `25` in production. Have you tried using `587`?

Comment: It sounds like your ISP blocks outbound SMTP. Either ask them to unblock it, or find out how they want you to send email - ask them, it’s what you’re paying them for.